# Page Method Is Not Executing

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, scriptmanager

I am trying to make improvements to a SharePoint 2010 site and am running into difficulties calling a PageMethod. Here is the script I'm attempting to execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BindingTitle() {
        alert("number one");
        PageMethods.BindTitle(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
        alert("number two");
    }

    function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
        alert("it worked!");
    }
    function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
        alert("it didn't work!");
        alert(error);
    }

</script>
```

The control tied to the script is within a table but for the sake of brevity, it looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="BindingTitle()"> alsdjlfajlskdjfla</th> //this is the control
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

and the web method placed in the code behind looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static void BindTitle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("things are happening");
    }
```

The line in the script, "PageMethods.BindTitle(OnSucceeded, OnFailed) is not executing. When the control is clicked, the alert saying "number one" displays, but the "number two" never shows (When the page method is commented out, it does). The only thing I can think of that could be the cause of this is the script manager. It is declared in the master page for this package which is something I do not want to change. But the script manager is used for a lot of different things and I am not familiar enough with the intricacies of web development to know how this affects it on my page. The definition of the script manager looks like this:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
```

Is there a way I could disable this script manager on my page so I could declare my own, simpler one? It should also be noted that this is a fairly large site with several pages that depend on the previously declared script manager. Most of code for these sites is exceptionally messy and was written by a person who is no longer working for this company. I say this just to clarify that some changes that would affect other pages are not feasible given my available time because of the amount of testing and debugging necessary after such a change.

If I left anything out, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Do a View Source on the page and check if the page method code is there (there should be a bunch of JS directly in the page you may search for PageMethods or the method name). Also if the second alert is not executing the browser should give an error (depending on your browser and tools the error indication is displayed differently)

Comment: A few suggestions: (1) if you are doing this on a single page, you should be using a ScriptManagerProxy instead of a new ScriptManager.  (2) If you need to override the existing scriptmanager, you should look at doing so on either a master page or on a page layout.  [This example may also be helpful](http://pradeepkvd.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/ajax-extenders-in-sharepoint-2010/), even though it's woefully formatted.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Console.WriteLine in an ASP.NET app won't do anything. You should use Debug.WriteLine. That way you can see the output in Visual Studio's Debug window

Comment: I'm aware that the Console.WriteLine won't do anything, I simply had it in there so I could set a break point. Sorry for not clarifying that in my answer. The method code does not appear in the page source. Does this mean I do not have the method in the correct location? It is currently located in the page's codebehind. I'm looking into what exactly a ScriptManagerProxy is now (sorry I'm an inexperience web developer).

Comment: I should also not that I am not experiencing any error messages in FireFox or IE.

Comment: You don't need a ScriptManagerProxy in this case. I just tried and ScriptManager on the master page can handle PageMethods from nested pages just fine without anything else. Are you sure you cant find code like this: var PageMethods = function() {
PageMethods.initializeBase(this); ... on the page?

Comment: In the page source I've searched for both PageMethods and BindTitle (my function name) and each only occurs in one instance which is the javascript code that I have posted above. I can't find the actual method code in the page source anywhere.

Comment: The PageMethods definition should be there by virtue of "EnablePageMethods = true" alone. Are you sure you are looking at the same MasterPage and that the ScriptManager has its property set to true?

Comment: For the sake of safety, I have gone through and checked every ScriptManager declaration in the entire project and made sure EnablePageMethods is set to true and the code is still not displaying in the source. I'm running out of hope here. It isn't possible to change the value of the EnablePageMethodField outside of the declaration, is it? Could this possibly be a problem somehow linked to the fact that this is a Microsoft SharePoint site?

Comment: It is certainly possible to change the property in code behind. You may want to search the entire project for the property name. BTW don't enable it on pages you don't need it because you will end up with a lot of script that you don't need on other pages.

I don't know for sure if Sharepoint can cause this problem but I would be really surprised if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and it works perfectly. However, when I changed the `ScriptManagers` `EnablePageMethods` property to `false`, it starts behaving as you described it, i.e. it executes the first alert and stops there. Make sure that the property isn't being set to false anywhere in the code.

Comment: Ultimately, this ended up being the problem so I will accept your answer. I would also like to give great thanks to Stilgar for his help. The reason I was experiencing more trouble was because I put the WebMethod in the codebehind for the User Control I was editing (This made sense because the script that called the method was in the user control's aspx file) but I moved the method to the page containing the user control's codebehind and it works. I appreciate all your help everyone! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem last week and none of the things I could find in the forums resolved the issue.  I had set up a new web application (from a VS template) and then copied several pages into the project.  Several of the pages used PageMethods.  The pages were all working in the old project.  However, the jscript code that called the PageMethods was not working in the new project.  The jscript was hit, but it was acting like the PageMethod was not being hit.  I set breakpoints in the PageMethod code and it was never hit. (I verified in the old project that the breakpoints did hit.)  The return was also hitting the "Successful" jscript method, but nothing else was returned.

What I finally found was that the new template had a couple of calls in the Global.asax.cs file that I did not recognize.

```
        // Code that runs on application startup
        //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Commenting out the RouteConfig and BundleConfig calls allowed the PageMethod calls to work just fine.  I am not sure what these two calls did, but I am working now.

Just wanted to share this, in case other encountered the issue.

Comment: I tried commenting out these lines which were in the Global.asax file in a VS2013 Asp Forms Project and got a web error "'respond' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'. Commenting out only RegisterBundles gave the same error. Commenting out RegisterRoutes resulted in Page Method returning Fail rather than success.